# Hibernate + SQL Server: One Transaction blocks all other transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am developing a server application with Spring + Hibernate + SQL-Server and i recognized that all my transactions are blocking other transaction, even if other transactions do not touch the same tables / rows and there are no relationships between this tables.

Here is a screenshot:

[Transaction Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy1QP.jpg)

The screenshot shows that a delete statement on table A blocks a select statement on table B. But there is no relationship between the tables.
In my understanding a transaction should only lock a table or row and another transactions that will hit the locked table or row will be blocked.
But why are all transactions blocked?
Do i missunderstand anything?

Comment: Do you have triggers on the tables? Triggers commonly execute code to modify other tables, such as for auditing/logging purposes, and can cause locks on seemingly unrelated tables.

Comment: The database shema is created by jpa. If jpa does not append triggers on the tables then there must be no triggers there. Or is / do / can jpa do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution was found:**

The process was a copy-process. At the beginning i opened a transaction for the whole process and copy n-objects in this process. When i need to do selects while copying the selects were blocked. So i decide to open a transaction everytime i copy one object and after that copying-process close the transaction for this one object. So selects are no longer blocked. This design is like the copy-process in Windows. If you decide to cancel the copy-process the already copied files will stay. Like in my case the already copied objects will stay cause the transaction was closed and committed for every object separatly.